# Juego del ahorcado en C# 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Tags: c#

estoy trabajando en un juego del ahorcado con C# tengo este método para comparar si la letra que introduce el usuario corresponde a la letra de la palabra que hay que adivinar, y actualiza las letras según sea el caso, el problema es que me esta arrojando esta excepcion: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' Como si un objeto estuviera con un valor nulo pero no se cual puede ser,

Agradeceria su ayuda.

```
  void Compara(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Boton presionado se desactiva
            bool encontrado = false;
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
            btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
            btn.Enabled = false;

            // Compara la letra seleccionada con las letras de la palabra
            for (int indiceRevisar = 0; indiceRevisar < PalabrasAdivinadas.Length; indiceRevisar++)
            {

                if (PalabrasAdivinadas[indiceRevisar] == Char.Parse(btn.Text))
                {

                    // Si existe la letra actualiza la palabra agregando el valor correspondiente
                    Button tbx = this.Controls.Find("Adivinando" + indiceRevisar, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;

                   // EN ESTA LINEA ME APARECE EL ERROR DE LA EXCEPCION
 tbx.Text = PalabrasAdivinadas[indiceRevisar].ToString();
                    PalabrasAdivinadas[indiceRevisar] = '-';
                    encontrado = true;

                }


            }

            // Verifica si todas las letras de la palabra estan destapadas
            bool Ganaste = true;

            for (int indiceAnalizadorGanador = 0; indiceAnalizadorGanador < PalabrasAdivinadas.Length; indiceAnalizadorGanador++)
            {
                // Si el usuario tiene letras pendientes por destapar se cambia el estatus
                if (PalabrasAdivinadas[indiceAnalizadorGanador] != '-')
                {

                    Ganaste = false;

                }

            }

            // Si el estatus de la variable no cambia quiere decir el usuario gano.
            if (Ganaste) { MessageBox.Show("Ganaste ok, ok"); btnIniciarJuego.Image = Properties.Resources.boton3; }

            if(!encontrado)
            {
                Oportunidades = Oportunidades + 1;
                picAhorcado.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ahorcado" + Oportunidades);


                // Si las oportunidades ya se acabaron(mostrar la palabra)
                if (Oportunidades == 8)
                {

                    lblMensaje.Visible = true;
                    for (int IndiceValorLetra = 0; IndiceValorLetra < PalabraSeleccionada.Length; IndiceValorLetra++)
                    {

                        Button btnLetra = this.Controls.Find("Adivinado" + IndiceValorLetra, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
                        btnLetra.Text = btnLetra.Tag.ToString();

                    }

                    // Desactiva las fichas y cambia el botón de reinicio
                    flFichasDeJuego.Enabled = false;
                    btnIniciarJuego.Image = Properties.Resources.boton3;

                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: cuando te sale la excepcion te dice en que linea es el problema.

Comment: En esta linea  btnLetra.Text = btnLetra.Tag.ToString();

Comment: le estas queriendo hacer ToString a tag y ese es null, en tu parseo a button, comproba que btnLetra  no sea null

Comment: Ya intente pero no funciono sigue apareciendo que codigo me sugieres que le añada para comprobarlo?

Comment: if(btnLetra != null) {}

Comment: En que parte del codigo lo agrego? porque al agregarlo al inicio del codigo, me dice que el nombre btnLetra no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: El error no aparece en esa linea de codigo, aparece mas arriba en esta linea  Button tbx = this.Controls.Find("Adivinando" + indiceRevisar, 
true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;  antes de la variable bool Ganaste;